# How to show dynamic custom actions by selected custom filter in Django

Tags: python, django

```
class EvidenceFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Evidence')
    parameter_name = 'evidence'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):            
        return EVIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICES

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            if self.value() == 'pending':                    
                return queryset.filter(Q(profile__identity_verified='pending') & (Q(person_id_status='pending') | Q(person_selfie_status='pending') | Q(org_certificate_status='pending') | Q(org_taxid_status='pending')))
            elif self.value() == 'accepted':
                return queryset.filter(Q(profile__identity_verified='pending') & ((Q(person_id_status='accepted') & Q(person_selfie_status='accepted')) | (Q(org_certificate_status='accepted') & Q(org_taxid_status='accepted'))))
            elif self.value() == 'rejected':
                return queryset.filter(Q(profile__identity_verified='pending') & ((Q(person_id_status='rejected') | Q(person_selfie_status='rejected')) | (Q(org_certificate_status='rejected') | Q(org_taxid_status='rejected'))))
        else:
            return queryset

class EvidenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'profile', 'person_id_status', 'person_selfie_status', 'org_certificate_status', 'org_taxid_status')
    list_filter = (EvidenceFilter,)
    actions = ['make_approved', 'make_denied']

    class Meta:
        exclude = []

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(EvidenceAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if self.list_filter[0].value()=='pending':
            if 'make_approved' in actions:
                del actions['make_approved']
            if 'make_denied' in actions:
                del actions['make_denied']
        return actions

    def make_approved(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        for evidence in queryset:
            evidence.profile.identity_verified = "approved"
            evidence.profile.save()
    make_approved.short_description = "Approve selected evidences"

    def make_denied(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        for evidence in queryset:
            evidence.profile.identity_verified = "denied"
            evidence.profile.save()
    make_denied.short_description = "Deny selected evidences"
```

In *get_actions* function of *EvidenceAdmin* ModelAdmin class I am going to give special condition like that EvidenceFilter's selected value equal `*pending*`.

```
if self.list_filter[0].value()=='pending':
```

But I can't use the *self.list_filter[0].value()* to get the selected value of EvidenceFilter.
I get the following error because of it.

```
TypeError at /admin/securities/evidence/
value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Any suggestions or improvements are Welcome. Need some guidance on this... Thanks...